# javascript button onclick press only works once

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I am quite new to Javascript, and have the following question:

HTML:

```
<div id="button"></div>
```

JS:

```
for (var items in $scope.data.users){
    if ($scope.data.users.hasOwnProperty(items)) {
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML += "<button onclick='console.log(5)'>"+items+"</button>";
        console.log(items);
    }
}
```

So far it works that all users in my json object are read and a button is created for each item, and when I click on a button, it shows the correct test "5" in the console.
However, when I repeat the click, there comes an error, and I do not know why...

Comment: ...and what does the error say?

Comment: Look at the markup that gets generated, see what the resulting `onclick` attribute shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your array, or the scope, is changed on the click event.

Although the following example is not written with (what I believe) your Angular modules, it does work and iterates over a list, creating buttons and nót throwing any errors or exceptions. Basically it is the same code with a different array. Try to find the difference between this and your own code.

The only thing I changed, is making `$scope.data.users` an array of integers.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

for (var items in arr){
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(items)) {
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML += "<button onclick='console.log(5)'>"+items+"</button>";
        console.log(items);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="button"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same problem, try your code in https://jsfiddle.net/ and there will be the same error (f12-console). The first click works, further not...

Comment: It says however {“error”: “Please use POST request”} in jsfiddle when clicking on the error message- maybe that's the reason why it doesn't work? Any ideas how to "post this request"? Thanks :D

Comment: Oh my I feel so stupid! It does not log repeats, so everything was working. Sorry and thanks for your help!